# Scala Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: game, functional-programming, scala

This is my first Scala game.  I would love some feedback on my coding style, or your brief input on how you would do it.

```
object tictactoe extends App {
  def tttFormat(board: Array[Char]): String =
    "|" + board(0) + "|" + board(1) + "|" + board(2) + "|\n" +
    "|" + board(3) + "|" + board(4) + "|" + board(5) + "|\n" +
    "|" + board(6) + "|" + board(7) + "|" + board(8) + "|\n"
  println("Enter the number of the square you want to occupy!\n"+
      tttFormat(GameObj.board))
  while(GameObj.atPlay) {
    println(tttFormat(GameObj.updatedStateArray))
  }
  GameObj.nextTurn
  println("game over! " + GameObj.nextTurn + "'s win!")
}


object GameObj {
  val board: Array[Char] = Array('1','2','3',
                                 '6','5','4',
                                 '7','8','9')
  var whosTurn = false

  def nextTurn: Char = {
    whosTurn = !whosTurn;
    if (whosTurn) 'X' else 'O'
  }

  def atPlay: Boolean = 
    !(board(0) == 'X' && board(1) == 'X' && board(2) == 'X') &&
    !(board(3) == 'X' && board(4) == 'X' && board(5) == 'X') &&
    !(board(6) == 'X' && board(7) == 'X' && board(8) == 'X') &&
    !(board(0) == 'X' && board(4) == 'X' && board(8) == 'X') &&
    !(board(6) == 'X' && board(4) == 'X' && board(2) == 'X') &&
    !(board(0) == 'X' && board(3) == 'X' && board(6) == 'X') &&
    !(board(1) == 'X' && board(4) == 'X' && board(7) == 'X') &&
    !(board(2) == 'X' && board(5) == 'X' && board(8) == 'X') &&
    !(board(0) == 'O' && board(1) == 'O' && board(2) == 'O') &&
    !(board(3) == 'O' && board(4) == 'O' && board(5) == 'O') &&
    !(board(6) == 'O' && board(7) == 'O' && board(8) == 'O') &&
    !(board(0) == 'O' && board(4) == 'O' && board(8) == 'O') &&
    !(board(6) == 'O' && board(4) == 'O' && board(2) == 'O') &&
    !(board(0) == 'O' && board(3) == 'O' && board(6) == 'O') &&
    !(board(1) == 'O' && board(4) == 'O' && board(7) == 'O') &&
    !(board(2) == 'O' && board(5) == 'O' && board(8) == 'O')

  def updatedStateArray: Array[Char] = {
    val in: Int = Integer.parseInt(readLine()) - 1
    board.update(in, nextTurn)
    board
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Whether Scala or any other language, it's not a good sign when you have big blocks made of pasted/copied lines (tttFormat, board and atPlay).  There is some logical structure to those repeated lines and you should code that instead of copying lines.
- There is a bug: the middle row is inverted (654 instead of 456).
- The line asking for the player move should probably be in the while-loop.  Just my opinion.
- To keep good "separation of concerns", the player input should be read in the main loop and passed to the method that updates the board.
- The nextTurn followed by nextTurn at the end to get the winner is "hacky".